# Google service account on a private window doesn't preview video

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm trying to access and preview a video from my google drive using google service account, it works perfectly when i'm logged in my google account, but I need it to be able to preview the video even if i'm not logged in. When I call it on a private window for example it brings all the data, id, name, but the preview mode doesnt work. Do you guys have any idea what can I do to fix it?

Thank you.

test.php file:

```
require_once '/vendor/autoload.php';

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=Drive.json');

$client = new Google_Client();

$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setSubject($mySubject);

$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$response = $service->files->listFiles(array(
        'q' => "name='test.mp4'",
        'spaces' => 'drive',
        'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
    ));

$file = $response->files[0]; 
printf("Arquivo: %s (%s)\n", $file->name, $file->id);
$url = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/". $file->getId() ."/preview";

?>
<iframe src="<?php echo $url ?>" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

Comment: preview Works From within the Google drive web app service account don't have access to that.  I don't think you are going to be able to do this

Comment: There is nothing I could do to set it? headers? session? thank you for your reply though

Comment: No service accounts dont have access to the web version of Google drive.